# After migrating vuejs 2 to 3 i am getting webpack errors Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I was trying to update my vue 2 to vue 3 project. i upgraded my project with the use vue plugin. and it update my project but when i run my project.it gives me error of Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined.and after so many tries i am not able to solve it.and i dont have too much knowledge about webpack.so please check it and let me know how to fix it.
here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "shopify-theme-lab",
  "version": "2.6.2",
  "description": "Customizable modular development environment for blazing-fast Shopify theme creation",
  "author": "Sergej Samsonenko <contact@sergej.codes>",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production BROWSERSLIST_ENV=production BROWSERSLIST_CONFIG=.config/.browserslistrc node_modules/.bin/webpack --config .config/webpack/webpack.prod.js",
    "lint": "npm-run-all lint:*",
    "deploy:dev": "shopify-themekit deploy --env=dev --config .config/shopify/shopify.dev.yml --allow-live",
    "deploy:live": "shopify-themekit deploy --env=live --config .config/shopify/shopify.live.yml",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development BROWSERSLIST_ENV=development BROWSERSLIST_CONFIG=.config/.browserslistrc node_modules/.bin/webpack --config .config/webpack/webpack.dev.js --watch",
    "lint-fix": "node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix src/**/*.{js,vue} --config .config/.eslintrc.js",
    "lint:css": "node_modules/.bin/stylelint src/**/*.{vue,css,sass,scss} --config .config/.stylelintrc.js",
    "lint:js": "node_modules/.bin/eslint src/**/*.{js,vue} --config .config/.eslintrc.js",
    "open:dev": "shopify-themekit open --env=dev --config .config/shopify/shopify.dev.yml",
    "open:live": "shopify-themekit open --env=live --config .config/shopify/shopify.live.yml",
    "reloader": "node node_modules/shopify-theme-lab-reloader",
    "settings:dev": "shopify-themekit --env=dev download config/settings_data.json --config .config/shopify/shopify.dev.yml",
    "settings:live": "shopify-themekit --env=live download config/settings_data.json --config .config/shopify/shopify.live.yml",
    "shopify:init": "npx themelab shopify:init",
    "shopify:themes": "shopify-themekit get --list",
    "shopify:watch": "cross-env-shell shopify-themekit watch --env=dev --allow-live --config .config/shopify/shopify.dev.yml --notify=http://localhost:$npm_package_config_reloader_serverPort/reload",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel --silent --race dev reloader shopify:watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.2",
    "shopify-buy": "^2.11.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "v-calendar": "^2.3.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.20",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.18.0",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.15",
    "@shopify/themekit": "^1.1.7",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glob-all": "^3.2.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.13",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "progress-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.12",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.12",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "shopify-theme-lab-reloader": "^2.1.3",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.13.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^5.0.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vue-next": "~0.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^5.35.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  },
  "config": {
    "reloader": {
      "serverPort": 5000,
      "webSocketPort": 5050,
      "delay": 2000,
      "indicator": true
    }
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

and here is my webpack file

```
const { cacheTimestamp } = require("./cacheBuster");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ProgressPlugin = require("progress-webpack-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config({
  path: path.join(__dirname, "../.env"),
});

const entries = glob
  .sync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../src/layout/*"))
  .reduce((entries, entry) => {
    const entryName = path.parse(entry).name;
    entries[`layout-${entryName}`] = path.resolve(__dirname, entry);
    return entries;
  }, {});

module.exports = {
  stats: "minimal",
  entry: entries,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../shopify/assets/"),
    filename: `[name].${cacheTimestamp}.js`,
    clean: {
      dry: true,
    },
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: "named",
    mergeDuplicateChunks: false,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((?!(moment)).*)[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".vue", ".json"],
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "../../src/"),
      $: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../shopify/"),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: "/",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  external: {
     vue: "Vue",
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    /**
     * don't clean files with the 'static' keyword in their filename
     * docs: https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin
     */
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
      cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ["**/*", "!*static*"],
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      excludeChunks: ["static"],
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./script-tags.html"),
      filename: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "../../shopify/snippets/script-tags.liquid"
      ),
      inject: false,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
      },
      meta: {
        cacheTimestamp,
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      excludeChunks: ["static"],
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./style-tags.html"),
      filename: path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "../../shopify/snippets/style-tags.liquid"
      ),
      inject: false,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
      },
      meta: {
        cacheTimestamp,
      },
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(dotenv.parsed),
    }),
    
  ],
};
```

please check it let me know if we can change anything to fix it.

Comment: Please, show the entire error. Is it `vue` or `Vue`? There's a big difference. Regardless of that, you can't just upgrade Vue and leave other Vue libraries intact. They won't work with Vue 3, unless they were specifically were designed to support both, which is rarely the case. And they rarely have a drop-in replacement, so you usually need to rewrite parts that use them with new libs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.